# How does one prove the following using natural deduction: $a ∧ ¬a \vdash b ∧ ¬b$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove the following using natural deduction and this is what I have so far. I am not sure, however, if this is entirely correct.

If I could get some verification and be pointed to the right direction, that would be great.

```
    a ∧ ¬a |- b ∧ ¬b
1     a ∧ ¬a     assump 0
2     b |- a ∧ ¬a 
2.1   b          assump 2
2.2  ¬b         ¬I 2.1
3     b ∧ ¬b    ∧I 2.1, 2.2
4    ¬b |- a ∧ ¬a 
4.1  ¬b          assump 4
4.2   b         ¬E 4.1
5     b ∧ ¬b    ∧I 4.1, 4.2
```

This is not a duplicate as the symbols and solutions provided with the question it being marked against are different.

Comment: @Mauro I don't see how the question which you have flagged is a duplicate? I have a complete solution which I am asking to be verified and the syntax seems to be different to what I am using in my answer

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you introduced this ⊥ in the answer to the question. What does that mean as i have not been taught that symbol in my course, is there another way of writing it?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am assuming then my solution for the question is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a ∧ ¬a$ is a contradiction we can derive anything from such a premise using explosion.

Here is a proof checker showing that we could use explosion in natural deduction to reach the goal:

[image]

The proof uses the following natural deduction rules:

- Conjunction elimination (∧E)
- Contradiction introduction (⊥I)
- Explosion (X)

See the text *forallx* for further details about these rules.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Negation introduction requires a contradiction to be derived from the assumption. Your premise is a contradiction, so just reiterate.

The negation elimination rule you are using appears to be Reductio Ab Absurdum, and operates similarly.  Different proof systems name negation rules differently, so it may be useful to note that you mean RAA.

Only *after* you have derived *both* conjuncts, may you *finish* with the conjunction introduction.

```
0  a ∧ ¬a |- b ∧ ¬b
1         a ∧ ¬a       assump 0
2         b |- a ∧ ¬a 
2.1         b          assump 2
2.2         a ∧ ¬a     reit 1
3        ¬b            ¬intro 2
4        ¬b |- a ∧ ¬a 
4.1         ¬b         assump 4
4.2         a ∧ ¬a     reit 1
5        b             ¬elim 4  (RAA)   
6        b ∧ ¬b        ∧intro 5,3
```